# jQuery Mobile, MVC 4 Razor, Page (or view) Change Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, jquery-events, razor-2

I'm sure that some folks have come across this scenario before.  I need JavaScript to fire every time the user navigates to a new View. Please see the shared view (stripped down) below:

The 2 events will fire when you first open the website, but not on subsequent navigation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport">
<div data-role="page" id="div_page" data-theme="ss">
<div data-role="content" role="main" id="div_body" class="ui-content">
@RenderBody()
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html> 

$(document).on("pageinit", "#div_page", function () {});
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

Which event captures the page change event? The "change" event? The "DOMContentLoaded" event?  Please advise.

Comment: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, each request will be ajax request while using jquery mobile. Though you can try with $(document).on('pagecreate', function(){...});

Comment: `pagecreate` = `pageinit`

Comment: I ended up using the "pageshow", for which fires after the new page shows. However, the "pagecreate" solved another issue I had, so the link and the answer you gave was helpful.  Thank you Omar!